# What does the ‡ symbol in the Chart Supplement (A/FD) designate?

Tags: flight-training, chart-supplement

In the Chart Supplement there is occasionally a `‡` symbol after the operating hours for control towers (and other time information) like what's shown below.

[image: AFD snapshot]

What does the ‡ symbol represent?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `‡` is what you're talking about - if not let me know & revert my edit :-)

Answer (score 17):

The ‡ symbol in the A/FD specifies that the location observes daylight savings time.

This is from the A/FD legend, which can be found online by going to the [online digital A/FD](http://aeronav.faa.gov/index.asp?xml=aeronav/applications/d_afd) and searching for an airport.  The *A/FD Legend* link will then be at the top of the search results (unfortunately the link changes every cycle so I can't include an exact link).

> **6 TIME CONVERSION**
>
> Hours of operation of all facilities are expressed
>   in Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) and shown as ‘‘Z’’ time. The
>   directory indicates the number of hours to be subtracted from UTC to
>   obtain local standard time and local daylight saving time UTC–5(–4DT).
>   ***The symbol ‡ indicates that during periods of Daylight Saving Time
>   effective hours will be one hour earlier than shown.*** In those areas
>   where daylight saving time is not observed the (–4DT) and ‡ will not
>   be shown. Daylight saving time is in effect from 0200 local time the
>   second Sunday in March to 0200 local time the first Sunday in
>   November. Canada and all U.S. Conterminous States observe daylight
>   saving time except Arizona and Puerto Rico, and the Virgin Islands. If
>   the state observes daylight saving time and the operating times are
>   other than daylight saving times, the operating hours will include the
>   dates, times and no ‡ symbol will be shown, i.e., April 15–Aug 31
>   0630–1700Z, Sep 1–Apr 14 0600–1700Z.

Comment: It is important to note that the period of daylight saving time is different in different countries. In Europe daylight saving time starts 0200L last Sunday in March too, but ends _last_ Sunday in _October_. And on southern hemisphere it's the other half of the year.

Comment: @JanHudec While that is true, it isn't really important here since this is an FAA publication that only covers US airports.  That quote is directly from the legend.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Or, alternatively, the answer is that the tower has the same (local) operating hours no matter if it's DST or not, i.e., it's always 9-5 local.  However, since all hours are written in Zulu and the conversion to Zulu and local can change depending on if it's DST or not, this provides a quick shortcut to duplicating every entry's times.

More than anything else, this is a cautionary note that one should never speak 'x Standard time' unless you mean it - just say 'x time' instead.